# Meteor Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

Has anybody encountered this error in Meteor:

```
I20160619-11:46:41.856(0)? { [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
W20160619-11:46:42.053(0)? (STDERR) js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem was solved here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7477

It is due to deprecated packages. In the link I sent, we were talking about the Meteor-CollectionFS package named "gridfs".

Solution was brought by badmark: He updated the package on his repo, forked from the deprecated one.
https://github.com/badmark/Meteor-CollectionFS

So what to do:

1.go on this repo, fork the entire MeteorFS-Collection locall

2.Copy the 'gridfs' folder into your packages folder in the root of your project (create the folder if doesn't exist).

3.Then you run meteor (Meteor will recognize the local version (0.3.4 in this case))